# Why I can't declare a table variable together with others declarations?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, syntax, sql-server-2012, declare

For example:

```
DECLARE
    @t TABLE(id int),
    @i int;

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

But using separate DECLARE statements works fine

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id int);

DECLARE
    @i int,
    @str varchar(10);

Command(s) completed successfully.
```

Why this happens? What is difference between table declaration and declaration of "usual" variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know "why", exactly, but I have a couple of guesses:

1. A table variable isn't as simple as an ordinary variable.  It's not just a place in memory:  behind the scenes, a temporary table is being created in `tempdb`.  So perhaps the designers of the language wanted to distinguish between it and the more simple variables.
2. Table variables have a more complex syntax than ordinary variable declarations. A declaration statement with multiple table variables plus multiple ordinary variables, plus variable initializations, could potentially get extremely complicated.  Perhaps the syntax would just be too messy (or too ambiguous: open to multiple interpretations) for the parser.